# Selenium+python при поиске элементов, дублирует первый

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

При написании автотеста, возникла следующая проблема.
На странице прокручиваемый список с данными клиентов.
Мне нужно найти определённого клиента и произвести с ним несколько операций.

Во код:

```py
def test()
    self.scrolling_page() # прокручиваем страницу полностью
    duplicates_item = WebdriverWait(self.driver, 
        10).until(EC.presence_off_all_element_located((By.XPATH, 
        "Xpath")))
    for item in duplicates_item:
        full_name = item.find_element(By.XPATH, "name_xpth")
        if full_name.text == exp_full_name:
           ......
```

На странице около 100 клиентов (пересчитывал в ручную)
Но он всегда проверяет первого клиента.
То есть у нас в списке 100 одинаковых клиентов. Кол-во элементов списка совпадает с ожидаемым, но они все одинаковые.

В чём может быть проблема????? уже всё перепробовал и поиск по `CSS` и по `CLASS_NAME`

XPATH вида `//div[contains(@class, 'class1 class2')]`

**UPD 1**
В общем выяснил, что в списке все объекты разные:

```py
print(item.get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

Примерный код для каждого клиента

```html
<div id="id_item" class="customize-dialog">
    <div id="id_sub_item1">
      <div id="id_item2" tabindex="0" role="button" label="Назад">
         <div id=id_item3 class="class_1"
               <span .....></span>
               <span ...></span>
               <label....>text....</label> # этот текст всегда от первого клиента
         </div>
         <div id =id_item4 class="class_1"></div>
         <div id_item5 class="class_2"></div>
      <div id="sub_item_2"></div>
         <div id=id_item6 class="class_11"></div>
         <div id =id_item47class="class_12"></div>
         <div id_item8 class="class_12"></div>
  </div>
```

По сути блок `div id="id_item2"` всегда от первого клиента, но при использовании `print(item.get_attribute("innerHTML")`, данные выводятся корректные.

И ещё возникла одна особенность, при  попытке нажать на чекбокс "выбрать всё" у нужного клиента(у каждого клиента несколько чекбоксов), происходит выбор у первого клиента и выбирается иногда галочка ещё у одного клиента, всегда разного, иногда  двух.... как будто, нужный нам блок у каждого клиента, ссылается на на какой то один объект

**UPD 3**
В итоге всё сводится к следующему:

1. В списке все объекты уникальные, при использовании `print(item.get_attribute("innerHTML")` выводятся корректные данные.

2.При попытке из любого из этих элементов достать необходимую информацию, путём `item_text = item.find_elemnt(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'class1 class2')"]).text` мы получим текст первого элемента (всегда).

3. При попытке взаимодейстовать с этим элементом, путём поиска дочернего, ситуация та же
4. Всё это относится к верхнему блоку, то есть с нижним блоком `div id="sub_item_2"` всё нормально и получаем мы корректную информацию.

Comment: Добавьте полный код и сайт источник для проверки

Comment: добавить не могу, т.к. проект коммерческий для внутреннего использования

Answer (score 1):

В общем проблема была в XPATH.
Я указывал XPATH через две `//`, то есть `//span[contains(@class, 'class1')]`
Следовательно, даже при условии поиска дочерних элементов, типа: `elem.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'class1')]")` он в любом случае парсит всю страницу, а так как данный XPATH не был уникальным, он всегда находил первый элемент.
Для поиска через XPATH имеено дочерних элементов, необходимо указывать `./`, то есть:  `./span[contains(@class, 'class1')]`